# continuous and inverse function problem

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $f:\Bbb{R^n} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only if for each subset $E \subseteq \Bbb{R^m}$ we have $$f^{-1}(E^\circ) \subseteq [f^{-1}(E)]^{\circ}$$, where $E^\circ$ denotes the interior of the set E.

Theorem: A function $f:\Bbb{R^n} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only if for each open set V in $\Bbb{R^m}$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\Bbb{R^n}$. A function $f: \Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R^n} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^m}$ is continuous on $\Omega$ if and only if for each open set V in $ \Bbb{R^m}$, $f^{-1} (V)$ is open relative to $\Omega$

$f^{-1}(E^\circ) \subseteq [f^{-1}(E)]^{\circ}$, what can we tell from that, and how does it lead to continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll do one direction and start the other. Suppose that $f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}E]\subseteq\operatorname{int}f^{-1}[E]$ for every $E\subseteq\Bbb R^m$. Let $V\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ be open; then

$$f^{-1}[V]=f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}V]\subseteq\operatorname{int}f^{-1}[V]\subseteq f^{-1}[V]\;,$$

so $\operatorname{int}f^{-1}[V]=f^{-1}[V]$, and $f^{-1}[V]$ is open. $V$ was an arbitrary open set in $\Bbb R^m$, so $f$ is continuous.

Now suppose that $f$ is continuous, and let $E\subseteq\Bbb R^m$. Let $U=f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}E]$; since $f$ is continuous, $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$, and clearly $U\subseteq\;$ . . . what? Can you finish it from here?